# GET file (content and filename) with axios

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

There is an API endpoint which offers a downloadable file - when accessing the url directly from the browser - the file is saved automatically. However, I would like to target the given endpoint from my app, and fetch the file name and content to a reducer within my app's redux store.

I'm using `axios` for all API requests. In this case, I'm trying to do it like this:

```
axios({
    url: API_ENDPOINT_URL,
    method: "GET",
    headers,
}).then((response) => {
    // do some stuff 
    console.log("response ", response)
})
```

In this setup, `response` contains only `data`, there is no filename. How to go about this?

Comment: so what does `response.data` contain?

Comment: "Browsers don't support downloading files through AJAX requests. You can check this stackoverflow.com/questions/32545632/… and also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206589/how-to-download-fetch-response-in-react-as-file for more insight and some workarounds " from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832836/download-files-from-authorized-file-server-using-javascript-fetch-and-rest-api-e

Comment: See [Get a file name before saving it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642818/4642212). Is it in `response.data.headers`?

Comment: @MaieonBrix - While your assumption about this use case is probably accurate, a little early to make that assessment. The OP may be looking at Byte (stream) data that can be used as a BLOB.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes you are absolutely right, I did rush to answer. I am sorry

Comment: It's better done on a server side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple state forword working example of a download file by Axios.

```
export async function apiGet<T = any>(
  url: string,
  config?: AxiosRequestConfig
) {
  return axiosInstance.get<T>(url, config);
}
```

Now on below function, we call API and get file. for download file, make sure to add configuration

> responseType: 'blob'

```
    const response = await apiGet(`document/download/${documentId}`, {
       responseType: 'blob'
    });

    // get file content
    const blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: response.data.type});
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    
    // get original file name
    const contentDisposition = response.headers['content-disposition'];
    let fileName = 'unknown';
    if (contentDisposition) {
        const fileNameMatch = contentDisposition.match(/filename="(.+)"/);
        if (fileNameMatch.length === 2)
            fileName = fileNameMatch[1];
    }
    //set file name 
    link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add a response type in axios that can be either stream or blob (depends on the file type)

```
axios({
  method:'get',
  url:'endpoint_url',
  responseType:'stream'
})
  .then(function (response) {
    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file_name.jpg'))
  })
```

This is straight from axios documentation. Let me know if you need something else

Comment: How does this get the file name?

Comment: Hey Jacopo - I didn't downvote you, but your answer assumes NodeJS. The OP used the term 'reducer' which implies ReactJS operating in the browser. `fs` is not available in the browser.

Comment: Yes sure I get your point, the "problem" is that for the example above I test it on node, to be able to reassemble the file. The thing is that in the frontend part you can create a Blob instead of using fs